# Recursive function is overflowing, why?

Tags: scala, recursion, overflow

The below function is overflowing, and I don't understand why. When run with x as 0, y as 0 and dim as 2, the result should be 6. However, I am getting an error indicating that some Long value in the function (either x or y) is 554 at the time of overflow. This should not be possible as x and y are both bounded by the dim value, which in my test is set to 2. 
Here is the code:

```
def lattice(dim: Long, x: Long, y: Long): Long = { 
  if (x == dim && y == dim) {
    1
  }
  if (x >= dim) {
    lattice(dim,x,y+1L)
  }
  if (y >= dim) {
    lattice(dim,x+1L,y)
  }
  else {
    lattice(dim,x+1L,y) + lattice(dim,x,y+1L)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing `else` in two places. This means that your final line runs even when `x >= dim`, causing x to exceed `dim`. Try this instead:

```
if (x == dim && y == dim) {
    1
} else if (x >= dim) {
    lattice(dim,x,y+1L)
} else if (y >= dim) {
    lattice(dim,x+1L,y)
} else {
    lattice(dim,x+1L,y) + lattice(dim,x,y+1L)
}
```

Comment: Also, is there any way that this function can be optimized to be tail-recursive?

Comment: @ChrisGrimm: I am probably not the best person to answer your new question.

Comment: @Chris: Partially. Some arms can be so-optimized. The only arm which can't (at least by the compiler) is the last one because the `+` needs to be applied to the result of two recursive calls.

Comment: Even the last one can be tail-call optimized if the result is accumulated.

Answer (score 1):

Chris:

Youd function is not tail recursive because in your last statement you have a sum. By chance this sum involves two calls to `lattice`. However, to be tail recursive your last statament must be a constant (like you did in your first `if`) or just a call to function itself (such as your 2 `else if`s.

I admit that I don't know how to change your function to be tail recursive. Depending of your alghoritm, perhaps it is not possible to do your function tail recursive.

Thanks,

Rafael Afonso